# Why is the Angular Generator option on Stackblitz not available?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I forked this tutorial from angular.io site: https://angular.io/start

One of the steps has you create a new component and so I right click the app folder but there is no "Angular Generator" option like it shows in the screen shot on their site. What am I missing?

[image]

I should see this instead:

[image]

Comment: I think that's an issue on stackblitz side. Please report a bug there https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues. It doesn't recognize Angular application because model has changed

Comment: are you sure you are using **Right** button of the mouse, and click on the app folder? -works for me in Chrome, Edge and FireFox for windows just checkeck now-

Comment: I encountered the same problem. It's strange, because when I create a new project of type Angular/TypeScript directly from the stackblitz home page, the Angular Generator works fine. One thing I noticed is, that the angular.io/start example shows a warning on the bottom left: "WebContainer is in Beta". This warning is not shown on the newly generated Angular project. I haven't found a significant difference between the two projects so far, but something's got to be different.

Comment: i am using macbook pro and chrome

Comment: @Eliseo Looks like you clicked on a wrong link. You can also check any example from Angular material library https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples I don't think it will also work for you.

Comment: @Eliseo Here's the link from getting started guide we're trying to open https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/getting-started-v0/stackblitz.html

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44079#issuecomment-961975093

Comment: I believe you had opened AngularJS [JavaScript] instead of Angular [TypeScript] IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There has been an [update](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44079) on the documentation about this. Hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) https://angular.io/start to see the uncached version

Comment: I did this and no joy.